# Removing a specific word from a file [Python 2.7.10] file 'object' has no attribute remove

Tags: python, file

I can't seem to figure out how to remove the word "end" from my text file.

```
print "Max input for today is 30 links"

file = open("tutorials.txt", 'r+')

counter = + 1

while counter <= 30:
    tutorial = raw_input("Enter Tutorial Link :")
    file.write(str(tutorial) + '\n')

 if tutorial == "end":
    file.remove("end") 
    break

file.close()
```

When i run the script i get this return : file 'object' has no attribute remove

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: break your loop once the input is `'end'` instead of writing it to the file?!

Comment: Dont know how i did not see that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should consider changing the name of your 'file' variable as to not shadow the built-in file(): https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function you can use to delete specific strings inside of text files, and will return an output file with the corrections:

```
inputfile = "tutorial.txt"
outputfile = "fixed_tutorial.txt"

def remove_strings():
    delete_list = ["end"]
    filein = open(inputfile)
    fileout = open(outputfile, "w+")
    for line in filein:
        for word in delete_list:
            line = line.replace(word, "")
        fileout.write(line)
    filein.close()
    fileout.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_strings()
```

The inputfile, of course, must be in the same directory / folder as the file that holds the information for this function.